# Paypal Sandbox and Live API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

are PayPal `Sandbox` and Live `API` the same? I keep getting a  Security header is not valid (10002)    error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different endpoints and would use different credentials, so no, they are not the same.  If you're getting security header that means your values are simply incorrect, or you're sending live credentials to the sandbox server or vise-versa.  Sounds like that's what you're doing.